# Change "Donate" to "Give Back" on blog Paypal button

Tags: php, open-source, paypal

I can't count the number of times I've been helped by an open source project or a library, or, as what prompted me to ask this question, a really good blog which has great instructional videos. But I never understood why these excellent resources always have a paypal "Donate" button (As if they're begging or something. Are these people forgetting that we owe them? but that's beside the point).

So I'd like to write a tutorial on how to change the paypal button from **"Donate"** to **"Give Back"**. I'm using PHP and haven't really used the PayPal API before. My guess is it's a small change: just create a button graphic and just replacing the CSS.

- Is that the case? and/or how would you go about doing this?
- From where do I get an open source PayPal image that says "Give Back". [OpenClipArt.org](http://openclipart.org) doesn't have any.

Any source code or CSS is appreciated

Comment: To be honest, if this was doable, I'm pretty sure you'd already have ran into one. PayPal's terms of service probably prohibit modifying the buttons.

Comment: There are two ways to modify the picture during button creation. But I'm not sure what exactly you want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not just change the image in the donate button code to whatever image you want? or am I missing something?

This is some sample paypal donate code I found in one of their [examples](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_donate_techview_outside):

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@mybusiness.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Team In Training">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="25.00">
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donate_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

you would just need to change the url to your image in this tag

```
<input type="image" src="/path/to/your/image.gif">
```